# Using Accord Audio library with Windows Phone 8.1 App (Not Silverlight)

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1, fft, accord.net

I'm currently building an application for Windows Phone 8.1 using C#,

The aim of the app is to assess audio signals from the device's microphone, initially for frequency,

I was hoping to use the Accord library to help with this but have run into these errors:

> XamlCompiler error WMC1006: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows
>   Metadata file 'System.Windows.Forms.dll'
>
> \Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\8.1\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(327,9):
>   Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Type universe cannot resolve
>   assembly: System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.

I'm fairly certain that this is arising due to the references included in the project but I'm not to sure,

Here is my current code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
    using Accord.Audio;
    using Accord.Controls;
    using Accord.DirectSound;
    using Accord.Imaging;
    using Accord.MachineLearning;
    using Accord.Math;
    using Accord.Statistics;
    using Accord;
    using AForge;
    using AForge.Controls;
    using AForge.Imaging;
    using AForge.Math;
    using AForge.Video;
    using Windows.Media.Capture;
    using Windows.Storage;
    using Windows.Storage.Streams;
    using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using Windows.Media;
    using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
    using Accord.Audio.Formats;
    using Accord.Audio.Windows;

    namespace Test2
    {
        public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private MediaCapture _mediaCaptureManager;
        private StorageFile _recordStorageFile;
        private bool _recording;
        private bool _userRequestedRaw;
        private bool _rawAudioSupported;
        private IRandomAccessStream _audioStream;
        private FileSavePicker _fileSavePicker;
        private DispatcherTimer _timer;
        private TimeSpan _elapsedTime;


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

            InitializeAudioRecording();
        }
        private static void DecodeAudioFile()
        {

            String fileName = "record.wav";

            WaveDecoder sourceDecoder = new WaveDecoder(fileName);

            Signal sourceSignal = sourceDecoder.Decode();

            RaisedCosineWindow window = RaisedCosineWindow.Hamming(1024);

            Signal[] windows = sourceSignal.Split(window, 512);

            ComplexSignal[] complex = windows.Apply(ComplexSignal.FromSignal);

            complex.ForwardFourierTransform();

            Debug.WriteLine(complex);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void InitializeAudioRecording()
        {
            _mediaCaptureManager = new MediaCapture();
            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
            settings.MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Other;
            settings.AudioProcessing = (_rawAudioSupported && _userRequestedRaw) ? AudioProcessing.Raw : AudioProcessing.Default;

            await _mediaCaptureManager.InitializeAsync(settings);

            Debug.WriteLine("Device initialised successfully");

            _mediaCaptureManager.RecordLimitationExceeded += new RecordLimitationExceededEventHandler(RecordLimitationExceeded);
            _mediaCaptureManager.Failed += new MediaCaptureFailedEventHandler(Failed);
        }

        private void Failed(MediaCapture sender, MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs errorEventArgs)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void RecordLimitationExceeded(MediaCapture sender)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }



        private async void CaptureAudio()
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Starting record");
                String fileName = "record.wav";

                _recordStorageFile = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

                Debug.WriteLine("Create record file successfully");
                Debug.WriteLine(fileName);
                MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);


                await _mediaCaptureManager.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, this._recordStorageFile);

                Debug.WriteLine("Start Record successful");
                _recording = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to capture audio");
            }

            DecodeAudioFile();
        }
        private async void StopCapture()
        {
            if (_recording)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Stopping recording");
                await _mediaCaptureManager.StopRecordAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("Stop recording successful");

                _recording = false;
            }
        }

        private async void PlayRecordedCapture()
        {
            if (!_recording)
            {
                var stream = await _recordStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                Debug.WriteLine("Recording file opened");
                playbackElement1.AutoPlay = true;
                playbackElement1.SetSource(stream, _recordStorageFile.FileType);
                playbackElement1.Play();
            }
        }

        private void Capture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Capture.IsEnabled = false;
            Stop.IsEnabled = true;
            CaptureAudio();
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Capture.IsEnabled = true;
            Stop.IsEnabled = false;
            StopCapture();
        }

        private void Playback_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PlayRecordedCapture();
        }
        private void backBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                Frame.GoBack();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance in resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original *Accord.NET Framework* is not accessible on other platforms than .NET.

There is an effort (of which I am responsible) for porting *Accord.NET* to mobile platforms via Portable Class Libraries. Several of these packages have been published on NuGet as well (prefix *Portable Accord*).

The *Audio* package is not published on NuGet, but you should be able to build it from source for *Windows Phone 8.1*. You can find the source for Portable Accord [here](https://github.com/cureos/accord).

Please note that only playback is supported, recording is not.